# How to Interpret DateTimeOffset column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, datetimeoffset

If I have a SQL column of type `datetimeoffset`, what is the value of the column telling me?

For example, if I see `2017-03-27 15:00:00.6866682 -04:00` is that LOCAL time?

Meaning, 3PM in EST and 7PM in GMT? Or is it GMT with an offset, meaning 3PM GMT and 11AM EST?

In other words, if a website logged `datetimeoffset` of user log in, and I (in New England) and my pal in Moscow logged in at the exact same time (3PM my time), would I see:

```
2017-03-27 15:00:00.6866682 -04:00
2017-03-27 22:00:00.6866682 +03:00
```

or:

```
2017-03-27 19:00:00.6866682 -04:00
2017-03-27 19:00:00.6866682 +03:00
```

Or, is it configurable per server? And if so, how would I check the setting?

Thanks. I have dealt with this before, but for some reason this knowledge simply will not stick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offset is reflected in the value.

`2017-03-27 19:00:00.6866682 +03:00` = `2017-03-27 16:00:00.6866682 +00:00`

http://rextester.com/YNJC2084

The offset is recorded as the offset in effect at the time. So if the offset for a timezone changes for day light savings, then you will see two different offsets for a given time zone depending on the time of year.

You can use [**`switchoffset()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/switchoffset-transact-sql) to change the offset, e.g.

```
select switchoffset(sysdatetimeoffset(),'-05:00')
```

returns `2017-03-27 15:44:35 -05:00`

Comment: So "19:00 +03:00" means "7PM Moscow time, 4PM GMT time". Excellent and thank you! I will do my best to remember this, but if I can't, at least it is linked forever in my stack exchange account!